# java.util.NoSuchElementException when using inject method of groovy List

Tags: list, exception, groovy, closures

i try to get the AND logic among boolean elments from groovy list .

```
def list=[true,false,true];
```

For example , when i apply inject as following :

```
 list.inject{a,b->a && b};
```

i get

```
 true && false && true=false
```

However , when i apply this closure to an empty list i get this error message

```
 Cannot call inject() on an empty collection without passing an initial value.
```

How can passing initial value to avoid this exception ? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject with no initial parameter uses the first element in the list as the initial value, and then runs the closure over all further elements in the list.

If the list is empty, it cannot get the initial value, so you need to specify an initial parameter to `inject`:

ie:

```
list.inject( true ) { a, b -> a && b }
```

This will return `true` for empty lists, but in your original example will return `false`, as it will evaluate:

```
true && true && false && true
```

Obviously, if you're doing `or` instead of `and`, you should pass `false` as the inital parameter:

```
list.inject( false ) { a, b -> a || b }
```